# How to select items from table by using a @local_variable table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Currently in a simple form i have the following declared table in code:

```
declare @FileIDs as table
(
    ID int not null
)
```

and i can fill it up e.g. manually like this:

```
insert into
    @FileIDs
values
    (1)

insert into
    @FileIDs
values
    (2)

insert into
    @FileIDs
values
    (3)
```

Also i have another table called `Files` and i like to select only those items, that have the same ID.

So I've tried the following approaches, but both fail:

```
select
    *
from
    Files
where
    ID in
    (
        @FileIDs
    )

select
    *
from
    Files
    inner join @FileIDs
    on Files.ID = @FileIDs.ID
```

Any ideas on how i can solve this problem?

Comment: What is the error you get and what is the type of Files.ID?

Comment: just give an alias to @FileIDs

Comment: Will this table need to be dropped in order to redo the insert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do either

```
select 
    * 
from 
    Files 
where 
    ID in 
    ( 
        SELECT ID FROM @FileIDs 
    ) 



select 
    f.* 
from 
    Files f
    inner join @FileIDs fid
    on f.ID = fid.ID
```

In the first query your syntax was incorrect. You had to have

```
SELECT ID FROM @FileIDs
```

And in the second you need to assign an alias to the table variable.

Comment: And this would work even if the @ variable had more than one column??

Answer (score 1):

do it like this

```
declare @FileIDs as table
(
    ID int not null
)
insert into
    @FileIDs
values
    (1)

insert into
    @FileIDs
values
    (2)

insert into
    @FileIDs
values
    (3)

;


select
    *
from
    Files
    inner join (select * from @FileIDs) F
    on Files.ID = F.ID
```

Comment: Why `inner join (select * from @FileIDs) F` instead of simply `inner join @FileIDs F`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. i didnt edit as answer is already selected

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
select * from Files 
where id in (select ID from @FileIDs)
```

The first attempt you made needed to have a column name in the subquery.